# Firebase - view.setText() - How to wait for response

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase to save some User-Control text in the database. I usually get a nullpointer exception because the onDataChange was not initially triggered. (I use an ValueEventListener)

How can I solve this problem?

Here the call:

```
sharedPref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("abc").child("ddd");

            ValueEventListener clubSettingsListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    firebaseClubSettingsModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseClubSettingsModel.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w("ClubSettingsService", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            };

            sharedPref.addValueEventListener(clubSettingsListener);

            if (firebaseClubSettingsModel == null) {
                firebaseClubSettingsModel = new FirebaseClubSettingsModel();
                //sharedPref.setValue(firebaseClubSettingsModel);
            }
```

Comment: please attach the call so we have a clear view of whats your problem

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manipulate your data outside of the onDataChange event since getting data from firebase is an asynchronous process so there is no guarantee that the call will be ended when you check its values.

You must be doing your validations and other logic inside the `onDataChange` listener because it will be triggered as soon as the data is available.

```
sharedPref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("abc").child("ddd");

ValueEventListener clubSettingsListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        firebaseClubSettingsModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseClubSettingsModel.class);
        if (firebaseClubSettingsModel == null) {
            firebaseClubSettingsModel = new FirebaseClubSettingsModel();
            sharedPref.setValue(firebaseClubSettingsModel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w("ClubSettingsService", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
sharedPref.addValueEventListener(clubSettingsListener);
```

Comment: Is it possible to wait until the data is available? Maybe with a splash-screen?

Comment: what do you mean by data is available? if `onDataChange` is triggered then the data is available

Comment: Simpler use-case: I have a button. The button-text is in the firebase database. If I show the view to the user he do not see a button-text. It is possible to show a default text (I have the model with default textes), but that is not a good solution.

Comment: @thomas I don't think you should be concerned about the delay between you show your view and the text is available and shown in the button, since firebase has almost no latency. If you really want to go forward with this you could start a loading spinner when the view is opened and then turn it off as soon as `onDataChange` is triggered.

Comment: I think, that is the solution. Because there are a lot of latency here (not only 4G)